# Using Akavache Database In Xamarin Forms Project

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, mobile, akavache

Using Visual Studio 2019
Xamarin Forms 4.2
.Net Standard 2.0 Framework

I am working on a Xamarin Forms project in which I am using Akavache to do some caching of the data which works fine, but I also would like to use the same database that Akavache creates to save some data to my own table.  Could someone please direct me to some code that can shows me how to do this?  I want have a table created based on a class model that I can preform CRUD operations on.

Thanks,
Kai

Comment: You could check the samples of Akavache on GitHub. https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache

Comment: Thanks Wendy!  I will check out the link you sent.

Comment: I looked at the code in the Akavache project and I didn't see anything to help with my question.  The strange thing is that I can see the "DatabasePath" value that is in my Akavache object, but the value of the property can only been seen and access during Debug mode.  I am using Visual Studio 2019 Professional.